# How To extend WP_Customize_Control

Tags: theme-development, theme-customizer

I'm looking for a way to add a new kind of control to the customize *live preview* panel. I have seen how to add new sections to the panel using 
`add_action( 'customize_register'...`

The control I want to implement is a different kind of color picker. In [a previous post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/34552/how-to-extend-a-class-in-wordpress), we see how to extend core classes to add widgets, but what I lack here is a hook that will enable me to bring my object into scope - WP_Customize_Palette_Control. At

You can see the [beginnings of the code here](https://gist.github.com/3120600). This code is in the `functions.php` file of my theme.

Thanks for any help.
Rob

Just updated the code. Now I have `require_once` to bring in the classes. So now I have no PHP errors but my new control HTML does not appear.

```
<?php

require_once( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-wp-customize-setting.php' );
require_once( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-wp-customize-section.php' );
require_once( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-wp-customize-control.php' );

class WP_Customize_Palette_Control extends WP_Customize_Image_Control {  
        public $type    = 'palette';
        public $removed = '';
        public $context;

        public function enqueue() {
                //wp_enqueue_script( 'wp-plupload' );
        }

        public function to_json() {
                parent::to_json();

                $this->json['removed'] = $this->removed;

                if ( $this->context )
                        $this->json['context'] = $this->context;
        }

        public function render_content() {
                ?>
                <label>
                        <span class="customize-control-title"><?php echo esc_html( $this->label ); ?></span>
                        <div>
                                <a href="#" class="button-secondary upload"><?php _e( 'Upload' ); ?></a>
                                <a href="#" class="remove"><?php _e( 'Remove' ); ?></a>
                        </div>
                </label>
                <?php
        }
}

//new WP_Customize_Palette_Control();


//add_action('customize_controls_init', 'WP_Customize_Palette_Control');

// add an option to the customize panel

function sci_customize_controls_init($wp_customize) {
    $wp_customize->add_section( 'themename_color_scheme', array(
        'title'          => __( 'Color Scheme', 'themename' ),
        'priority'       => 35,
    ) );

    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'themename_theme_options[color_scheme]', array(
    'default'        => 'some-default-value',
    'type'           => 'option',
    'capability'     => 'edit_theme_options',
) );


$wp_customize->add_control( 'themename_color_scheme', array(
    'label'      => __( 'Color Scheme', 'themename' ),
    'section'    => 'themename_color_scheme',
    'settings'   => 'themename_theme_options[color_scheme]',
    'type'       => 'palette',
    'choices'    => array(
        'value1' => 'Choice 1',
        'value2' => 'Choice 2',
        'value3' => 'Choice 3',
        ),
) );

}

add_action( 'customize_register', 'sci_customize_controls_init' );
```

Comment: Minor point, but unless your control is going into the WordPress core, don't use the WP_ prefix. Use your own plugin/theme name as the prefix for the class name.

Answer (score 15):

## Example and class for usage

You can see on my current theme, how it's possible to use this. Also you can usage the class. See this [class](https://github.com/bueltge/Documentation/blob/master/inc/theme-options.php) on Github an check the [`functions.php`](https://github.com/bueltge/Documentation/blob/master/functions.php) for include this.

## Start & init

You can register your custom settings for the theme customizer via the `customize_register`  hook:

```
add_action( 'customize_register', 'themedemo_customize' );
function themedemo_customize($wp_customize) {

    $wp_customize->add_section( 'themedemo_demo_settings', array(
        'title'          => 'Demonstration Stuff',
        'priority'       => 35,
    ) );

    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'some_setting', array(
        'default'        => 'default_value',
    ) );

    $wp_customize->add_control( 'some_setting', array(
        'label'   => 'Text Setting',
        'section' => 'themedemo_demo_settings',
        'type'    => 'text',
    ) );

    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'some_other_setting', array(
        'default'        => '#000000',
    ) );

    $wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Color_Control( $wp_customize, 'some_other_setting', array(
        'label'   => 'Color Setting',
        'section' => 'themedemo_demo_settings',
        'settings'   => 'some_other_setting',
    ) ) );

}
```

### In-Theme usage:

Use it, like in the example below ↓:

```
echo 'some_setting => ' .get_theme_mod( 'some_setting', 'default_value' )."\n";
echo 'some_other_setting => ' .get_theme_mod( 'some_other_setting', '#000000' )."\n";
echo 'non_existent_setting => '.get_theme_mod( 'non_existent_setting', 'default_value' )."\n";
```

### Adjustments

The you can also change the control:

```
$wp_customize->add_control( 'themename_color_scheme', array(
    'label'      => __( 'Color Scheme', 'themename' ),
    'section'    => 'themename_color_scheme',
    'settings'   => 'themename_theme_options[color_scheme]',
    'type'       => 'radio',
    'choices'    => array(
        'value1' => 'Choice 1',
        'value2' => 'Choice 2',
        'value3' => 'Choice 3',
        ),
) );
```

The default control-type is `text`. It creates a text box control. Another control-type is `dropdown-pages`, which creates a dropdown list of the WordPress Pages.

But that’s not all. There’re actually several more, but because they’re so custom, they’re declared differently.

This one makes use of OOP:

```
$wp_customize->add_control(
    new WP_Customize_Color_Control( $wp_customize, 'link_color', array(
        'label'    => __( 'Link Color', 'themename' ),
        'section'  => 'themename_color_scheme',
        'settings' => 'themename_theme_options[link_color]',
    ) )
);
```

### Additional notes:

- `WP_Customize_Upload_Control` – This gives you an upload box for files. However, you probably won’t use this directly,
  you’ll want to extend it for other things… like: 
  `WP_Customize_Image_Control` –
  This gives you the image picker and the uploader box. It extends the
  upload controller. You can see it in action on the custom background
  piece, where a user can upload a new file to be the background image.
- `WP_Customize_Header_Image_Control` – Because of the resizing action of
  the header piece, it needs a bit of special handling and display, so
  the `WP_Customize_Header_Image_Control` extends the
- `WP_Customize_Image_Control` to add that functionality. You can see it
  in action on the custom header piece, where a user can upload a new
  file to be the header image.

You can find more about "Theme Customizer" in [ottos blog](http://ottopress.com/).

**Update 11/06/2012**

Live Example for read possibilities and more examples, see the [open repo](https://github.com/bueltge/Documentation/blob/master/inc/theme-customize.php) for the source and the doku.

**Update 01/15/2013**

We have create a repo on [github with custom class](https://github.com/bueltge/Wordpress-Theme-Customizer-Custom-Controls) to use it, easy and ready. Maybe you can only use it or advance with your ideas and solutions.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, here's how to do this. Seperate your control class(es) to one or more new files.

You have a function or method hooked on customize_register, right? In that function or method require once your new files just before adding your custom controls. Then PHP won't complain about redefining classes.

Note: This will not work out of the box, but shows the trick.

```
add_action('customize_register', array('myAddControl', 'customize_register') );

class myAddControl{
public function customize_register()
{
    global $wp_customize;


            //This will do the trick
    require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/class-gctfw-theme-control.php');


    $wp_customize->add_section( 'gctfw_switch_theme' , array(
        'title'      => 'Switch theme',
        'priority'   => 25,
    ) );

    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'gctfw_select_theme' , array(
        'default'     => $wp_customize->theme()->get('Name'),
        'transport'   => 'refresh',
        'capabilities' => 'manage_options'
    ) );

    $myControl = new gctfw_Theme_Control( $wp_customize, 'gctfw_select_theme', array(
        'label'        => __( 'Select theme', 'mytheme' ),
        'section'    => 'gctfw_switch_theme',
        'settings'   => 'gctfw_select_theme',
    ) ) ;
    $wp_customize->add_control( $myControl );
    }
}//class
```

Answer (score 3):

You're never using your class. Try passing a new instance of your class to the add_control method:

```
$control_args = array(
  // your args here
); 

$my_control = new WP_Customize_Palette_Control(
                $wp_customize, 'themename_color_scheme', $control_args);

$wp_customize->add_control($my_control);
```

Also, I don't think WP knows that the option name for your setting is part of an array. Maybe it's better to have `themename_theme_options_color_scheme` instead of `themename_theme_options[color_scheme]`.

The class your extending belongs to the image upload control. If you're creating a color picker, you should probably extend the [WP_Customize_Control](http://svn.automattic.com/wordpress/trunk/wp-includes/class-wp-customize-control.php) class.

Comment: The Customizer [is aware of multidimensional settings](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/customizer-api/).

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness: An example on how to add a number field to the Theme Customizer.

```
class Customize_Number_Control extends WP_Customize_Control
{
    public $type = 'number';

    public function render_content()
    {
        ?>
        <label>
            <span class="customize-control-title"><?php echo esc_html( $this->label ); ?></span>
            <input type="number" size="2" step="1" min="0" value="<?php echo esc_attr(  $this->value() ); ?>" />
        </label>
        <?php
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think that's necessary, you can just pass `number` as the `type` for default Control, and use `input_attrs` to pass `step`, etc.

Comment: @IanDunn May you want to add an example as additional answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add backslash before the WP_Customize. So, it will be

```
class WP_Customize_Palette_Control extends \WP_Customize_Image_Control
```

, Because **backslash** assumed that the WP_Customize_Image_Control not from **same** Namespace

Let me know if it helped