# How do I add customize_register action AFTER adding a custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy, functions, theme-customizer

customize_register only works with the customize_register hook, and regardless of what hook I use to add the custom taxonomy, it always happens after customize_register.

(I want to loop through the list of terms from my custom taxonomy to create categories and custom options for each term)

EDIT:

This is the watered-down code in question of my template functions file:

```
register_taxonomy( 'brand', $object_types, $args );
add_action( 'muplugins_loaded', 'brand', 0 );
// ????? What Hook can I use here^ that will run before the 'customize_register' hook ????? //

function iartz_customize_register( $wp_customize ) {
    $brands = get_terms('brand');
    foreach($brands AS $brand){
        //Add color options for each term of taxtonomy 'brand'
    }
}
add_action( 'customize_register', 'iartz_customize_register' );
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit? Where/how are you running your code? Do you mean adding _term_ of taxonomy, or new taxonomy itself?

Comment: I don't know what are trying to achive??? I have worked on  200+ wordpress projects. And never got this type of situation... Am i missing something???

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I'm new to Wordpress development, so not very good with the terminology, but I figured it out.

Comment: If the answer was helpful to you, then consider accepting it. See »[What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)« and/or »[Why is voting important?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote)«, more information about the WordPress Development model is available at the [help].

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK it shouldn't be a problem to get taxonomy data at the `customizer_register` hook state. So that problem might have different reasons, but they aren't apparent from your question. Besides I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve, so you might want to fill the information gaps according to @Rarst's questions. Aside from that there are multiple methods out there to - for example - add a taxonomy dropdown to the customizer - I picked one and linked another one, see below.

---

**Disclaimer:**
This isn't my code, I add it here for completeness reasons, links to the source are added. Haven't tried it myself, but as far as I can tell there isn't anything wrong with it and it is working for people.

---

#### Code for taxonomy dropdown for theme customizer

→ [Source](https://gist.github.com/ericjuden/4656209) at Gist
→ according blog [article](http://ericjuden.com/2012/08/custom-taxonomy-control-for-the-theme-customizer/) by Eric Juden

This goes into the `functions.php`

```
add_action('customize_register', 'my_customize_register');
function my_customize_register($wp_customize){
require_once(TEMPLATEPATH . '/class/wp_customizer_taxonomy_dropdown.php');
 
$wp_customize->add_section('my_theme_blog_featured_categories', array(
    'title' => __('Blog: Featured Categories'),
    'priority' => 36,
));

$wp_customize->add_setting('featured_category_1', array(
    'default' => get_option('default_category', ''),
));

$wp_customize->add_control( new Taxonomy_Dropdown_Customize_Control($wp_customize, 'featured_category_1', array(
    'label' => __('Featured Area 1'),
    'section' => 'my_theme_blog_featured_categories',
    'settings' => 'featured_category_1',
    'args' => array(), // arguments for wp_dropdown_categories function...optional. array('taxonomy' => 'my_taxonomy')
)));
 
return $wp_customize;
}
```

This goes into a file called `wp_customizer_taxonomy_dropdown.php` located in a folder, located relatively to the functions.php, called `class`:

```
class Taxonomy_Dropdown_Customize_Control extends WP_Customize_Control {
    public $type = 'taxonomy_dropdown';
    var $defaults = array();
    public $args = array();
 
    public function render_content(){
        // Call wp_dropdown_cats to ad data-customize-setting-link to select tag
        add_action('wp_dropdown_cats', array($this, 'wp_dropdown_cats'));
 
        // Set some defaults for our control
        $this->defaults = array(
            'show_option_none' => __('None'),
            'orderby' => 'name', 
            'hide_empty' => 0,
            'id' => $this->id,
            'selected' => $this->value(),
        );
 
        // Parse defaults against what the user submitted
        $r = wp_parse_args($this->args, $this->defaults);
 
?>
    <label><span class="customize-control-title"><?php echo esc_html($this->label); ?></span></label>
<?php  
        // Generate our select box
        wp_dropdown_categories($r);
    }
 
    function wp_dropdown_cats($output){
        // Search for <select and replace it with <select data-customize=setting-link="my_control_id"
        $output = str_replace('<select', '<select ' . $this->get_link(), $output);
        return $output;
    }
}
```

This should with the additional information linked be pretty much self-explaining.

#### Additional similar approach

→ [WordPress Theme Customizer Custom Controls](https://github.com/bueltge/Wordpress-Theme-Customizer-Custom-Controls) by @bueltge;
→ Link to [source](https://gist.github.com/bueltge/4538951) of taxonomy dropdown example at Gist;
→ His [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/60683/22534) on here regarding this topic;

→ There are a couple of tutorials, articles and such available too, you'll find them easily yourself if you need to.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:
Both functions can be hooked to customize_register, and they will work fine.  The customize_register hook only works on the customize page, but I need the register_taxonomy function on both pages.  So, in order to use the register_taxonomy function on a front-end page call, I also called it on the init hook.

---

> "So that problem might have different reasons"

ialocin, You're right...

Without getting too deep, I was expecting the customize_register hook to call on every page call (because that's what the documentation says), but it doesn't, and that threw my troublshooting in completely the wrong direction.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: My pleasure! Not sure where you got the impression from that the hook does load on every page load, doesn't say so on the `customize_register` codex page. On the other hand it explicitly states »**Use the `init` action to call this function.**« on the `register_taxonomy` codex page. Anyway, problem solved.

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference says "customize_register Runs on every request, allowing developers to register new theme options and controls for use with the Theme Customization API"

Comment: Ok, I see it now, looked at singular page for `customize_register`, and BTW it is true, because the `customize_register` action is hooked to `wp_loaded`.